# cookie not being set in frontend browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, mern

since almost a week i've been trying to set cookie through backend in browser using node express but no matter how hard i try it never set the cookie i,am tired of repeating same steps i've set withCredentials to true in frontend and credentials  to "include" and credentials as true in backend origin as true or "http://localhost:3000" ive tried each and every way to set cookies through server to frontend but it never gets set and so after giving up i have to set cookie from frontend to browser using react-cookie module in frontend  but i always feel that  its not the right approach to do this

below is the cors origin credentials properties as true and "localhost:3000"

```
app.use(cors({
  origin:"http://localhost:3000",
  credentials:true,
}))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use('/highfit', router)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
```

below is the cors properties origin as true and credentials as "include"

```
app.use(cors({
  origin:true,
  credentials:"include",
}))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use('/highfit', router)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
```

this below code withCredentials as true and orign as "localhost:3000"

```
app.use(cors({
  origin:"localhost:3000",
  withCredentials:true,
}))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use('/highfit', router)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
```

none of these ways worked i've been way too much frustrated since many days

this below is my backend login api where i,am trying to set res.cookie or cookie through server

```
  const validuser = await UserModel.findOne({email:req.body.email});

     if(!validuser) return next({error:'sorry'})
        
      const validPassword = bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, validuser.password)

     if(!validPassword) return next({error:'sorry'})

     const token = jwt.sign({id:validuser._id}, process.env.SECRETKEY, {expiresIn:'2d'})

      const {password, ...rest} = validuser._doc
 
       const cookieOptions = {expires:new Date(Date.now() + expiresin),  httpOnly:true}

        res.cookie('user_cookie', token, cookieOptions, {httpOnly:true, secure:false} ).status(200).json({token:token, info:rest})
  
      console.log(rest)
```

this this last one is frontend login where i,am sending withCredentials true as third argument

ive tried many ways sending credentials as true or as "include"

but none worked

```
 
      const res = await axios.post('http://localhost:6590/highfit/loginuser',{
      
      method:"POST",
      headers:{"Content-Type":"application/json"},
      withCredentials:true,
 
      email,
      password,

      })
```

please help me solve this please please it'll be very helpful

Comment: This is going to sound totally unrelated, but please bare with me: what build system are you using. Vite? Webpack?

Comment: none i wasn't using any kind of build system or tool i,am just using tailwind css does  it has anything to do with it

Comment: Have you looked into the developer tools of the browser? Checking the network tab could show whether the `Set-Cookie` header is there and what it contains, and the console may contain additional messages if something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue , you can separate the cookie setting from the response which you want to send like this:

```
const cookieOptions = {
            expires: new Date(Date.now() + 2 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), // 2 days
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: false
        };

        res.cookie('user_cookie', token, cookieOptions);

       
        const { password, ...rest } = validUser._doc;
        res.status(200).json({ token: token, info: rest });
```